# why is __init__ module in django project loaded twice In the same process?

Tags: python, django, boost-python

I'm trying to wrap a c library in a high-level python interface with Boost.Python. One of the client contracts of the c library is that one of the handles can only be allocated once per-process. I was hoping I could enforce this contract on the python side by using a module global.

Here is my django component module's `__init__.py`. `PyGenTL` must only be created once per process!

```
import my_c_mod
import os

print "imager__init__()"
print os.getpid()
ptl = my_c_mod.PyGenTL()
```

Slightly relevant Boost.Python code

```
    BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_c_mod)
    {
        using namespace boost::python;

        // Create the Python type object for our extension class and define __init__ function.
        class_<PyGenTL>("PyGenTL")
            .def("sys_info", &PyGenTL::SysInfo)
            .def("list_cameras", &PyGenTL::ListCameras)  // 
            .def("start_camera", &PyGenTL::StartCamera)  // 
        ;
    }

    PyGenTL::PyGenTL()
    {
        try {
            std::cout << "PyGenTL ctor(): allocating GenTL Lib." << std::endl;
            Detail::ThrowError(GCInitLib());
            Detail::ThrowError(TLOpen(&hTL));
        } catch (boost::exception& e) {
            std::cerr << "PyGenTL ERROR! ";
            std::cerr << boost::diagnostic_information(e);
            std::cerr << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Note the print statements in the constructor, and os.getpid() in **init**. Here is the output from the django process. Note that two processes are created at the start of python, which is why two `PyGenTL`s are created. So far, so good.

```
C:\work\svn\sw\branches\python\GenTlServer>python manage.py runserver
imager__init__()
2264
PyGenTL ctor(): allocating GenTL Lib.
imager__init__()
2912
PyGenTL ctor(): allocating GenTL Lib.
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.3, using settings 'GenTlServer.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

Now, during page view, `__init__` gets called AGAIN within the same process (2912)

```
imager__init__()
2912
PyGenTL ctor(): allocating GenTL Lib.
ERROR (-1004): Requested module is in use.
PyGenTL ERROR! Requested module is in use.
[23/Jun/2011 18:02:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 76537
```

Sure, there is a work around for my particular problem by enforcing the singleton on the C side, but what is the python way to do it?

Comment: Could it be something to do with "runserver" forcing a code recompilation at every request?

Comment: Possibly, I am new to python so don't know that level of detail about the language. Recompile or not, it isn't calling my destructor before constructing the second `PyGenTL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's being loaded via two different entries in `sys.path`. Be consistent about your imports; I recommend importing the module *without* going through the project, e.g. `import <app>.<module>`. Configuring a WSGI container so that you're not dependent on `manage.py`'s mangling of `sys.path` will help.

Comment: Well that would explain the runtime warnings I get. C:\work\svn\sw\branches\python\GenTlServer\..\GenTlServer\imager\__init__.py:1: RuntimeWarning: to-Python converter for class std::vector<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > already registered; second conversion method ignored.

Comment: But I only see one entry in sys.path where my .pyd is available. Does manage.py search for things beyond sys.path?

Comment: No. `manage.py` is still Python code and has Python's limitations.

Comment: WSGI seems to be something I should look into farther. Some breadcrumbs for others.. 
http://archimedeanco.com/wsgi-tutorial/
http://pythonpaste.org/deploy/

Comment: Unaccepted this answer because WSGI seems to have been a distraction. I'm still going to use a web framework because I don't have time to rewrite the wheel. 

How do I fix sys.path when it doesn't even seem to be incorrect?

Comment: Yeah, your answer spurred me to understand a lot more about this (too?) easy to consume framework. Upvoted it again thanks for that. I've mitigated the core problem on the C side. Unfortunately I still don't quite understand how the module gets imported twice, and its still causing annoying exceptions.

Comment: After talking with several more people who have years of professional experience with django, the only answer I've ever heard was that django is a mess. Moving to flask to solve my problem here.